# Refile + S3: delete attachment and keep db record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I'm using `refile` gem to upload files to `S3` and having the following model

```
class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attachment :document, destroy: true
end
```

The respective table in database has columns `document_filename` and `document_id` to hold file metadata.

I need to remove file from `S3` and keep the respective row in DB (I need that to be able to display the name and delete date of that file).

I'm trying to do

```
data_file.document = nil
data_file.save()
```

But that removes filename. Is there a solution to remove file from S3 and keep `document_filename` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with defining 2 new columns in the respective model and copying the data to remain there upon removal.

This is way more consistent than keeping the malformed `refile` objects:

```
data_file.update_attributes!(
  file_name: data_file.document.filename,
  removed_at: DateTime.now,
  document: nil)
```